# adb shell pm list packages - Sort by newest

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am running this command:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

But there are a lot of packages. I've been using grep to find the ones I need,

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep name
```

but one of them doesn't seem to be showing. I want to see if the package name is somehow different. Is there a simple way for me to sort the adb listed packages from newest to oldest?

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell pm list packages | cut -d: -f2- | tr -d '\r' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'package={} ; echo $package ; adb shell dumpsys package $package | grep "firstInstallTime"'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**